# How to capture HTTPS traffic with Fiddler2 on Windows 8? Unable to generate certificate

Tags: windows-8, https, fiddler

How to capture HTTPS traffic with Fiddler2 on Windows 8?

While trying to capture HTTPS traffic under Windows 8 I get permanent messages "Unable to Generate Certificate" while browsing:

[image]

Renaming/moving files from `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA` don't help.